# How to restrict the data provider

Tags: testng

```
@DataProvider
public Object[][] listData()
{
    return new Object[][]{ 
    { "1171090666", "291450635","95"},
    { "144456671090466", "21391450535","395"},
    { "1444471090666", "2455391450635","4595"}
    };
}
```

Suppose first data is OK for me and I don't want to use second and third data, how can I restrict the data provider.

Answer (score 0):

```
@DataProvider(indices={0})
```

If you need that in runtime you have to implement some logic in your tests e.g. some status variable which marks all other tests as skipped or so.